# Python Syntax White Spaces

Tags: python, whitespace

Evening,

This is not necessarily pythonic, I know that going into it.  However, I can not get this to trigger properly at all.

What I'm trying to do is match two letters to items in "registers" which is getting done correctly, however I'm then trying to see if there is a white space after those two letters.  The white space is what's not getting picked up correctly.  I'm sure that I'm just botching up the sytax.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
registers = ['R0','R1','R2','R3','R4','R5','R6','R7']
whiteSpace = ['\t', ' ']
if (item[idx +2] + item[idx +3]) in registers and (item[idx +4] in whiteSpace):
```

Comment: you should probably look at pyparsing ... assuming you are trying to make some kind of grammar

Comment: No errors.  My test cases are just not working correctly.  Also to note I can't use any string helper classes or regest for this.

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong there.  We would need to see your particular item and idx values where it fails.

Comment: idx is just an integer at this point.  My test cases are "R3  " and R4    "

Comment: You realize that "R3 " and "R4 " won't work unless idx is -2, right?

Comment: Or if `item` has 2 characters before the register name.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing an example of what `item` is or why you're stepping through it with an index pointer. If it's just a string, as you say, you can reduce the test to the following:

```
if item[:2] in registers and item[-1] in whiteSpace:
```

You'll need to guarantee that item is 3 chars long, or put another guard in the condition.

As an aside, I like to use named slices for this sort of thing to make the intent more obvious:

```
code = slice(0, 2)
spacer = slice(-1)

if item[code] in registers and item[spacer] in whiteSpace:
```